# Items in Items RecyclerView(android, kotlin)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view

How to Realize Items in Items RecyclerView?

Should I Realize inner Items in ViewHolder of outer Items? Does it work correctly?

[image]

Should I Realize inner Items in ViewHolder of outer Items? Does it work correctly?[

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.